# mysql workbench not show columns - libglib2.0 issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I installed the new version of ubuntu 14:10 and I ran into the problem of mysql workbench and libglib. There is a guide on how to fix it. I read that you can downgrade libraries but even with synaptic I can solve the problem. Unfortunately, the version 6.2.4 of wb not yet been published.

Comment: For additional details, see http://bugs.mysql.com/74147

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution is explained at this link

https://www.notehub.org/2014/11/6/ok-so-here-is-the-entire-process-first-i

Answer (score 0):

A new release of MySQL Workbench has just been released (6.2.4) which fixes this problem.

Comment: Ciro, the release date was today (Nov 20, 2014).